# How would this JSON be represented with classes?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a JSON object that gets loaded as [String: Any]. I want to break down each part and turn the "Any" into an actual class. Here's one section of the JSON that I'm starting with:

```
"objects": {
"Yellow Fruits" = {
    name = "Bananas";
    numbers = (
        0,
        1
    );
};
"Red Fruits" = {
    name = "Strawberries";
    numbers = (
        2,
        4,
        5,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17
    );
};
}
```

I've tried representing these "fruits" with the following class:

class Fruit {
    var name: String?
    var officeIndicies: [Int]?
}

When I try to load this with

```
guard let fruits = json["objects"] as? [String: Fruit]
```

it seems that the Fruit class does not accurately represent what is in the json.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: What does the `numbers` property represent?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure because your code snippet isn't JSON

Comment: Basically it's impossible to **cast** `Any` to `[String: CustomStruct]`. And suggesting a `Decodable` solution is impossible, too, because the JSON is invalid.

Comment: Ahhh! thank you all. my program was printing the json differently than it should have :) fixed my problem